# clojure core async and servlet undeploy

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, clojure, java-threads, core.async

I am using Clojure's [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) in a servlet program. I am suspecting a memory leak in the program and I recognized that the total number of alive threads does not decrease when I undeploy my application from the application server (Glassfish).

My question is: **how can I clean up the unused core.async threads when I undeploy my application?**

I understand that core.async manages its own [thread pools](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/search?q=thread-pool-executor&unscoped_q=thread-pool-executor):

1. It uses a [cached thread pool](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/a25ae2fb44f0bc2828377866443ed638beeed9c9/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L429) for running `(thread)` macros. The threads in the pool get cleaned up automatically after 60 seconds of inactivity [according to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)).
2. However, it uses a [fixed thread pool](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/196f87dc21f55f601c867b796a0a421550b43c8f/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/exec/threadpool.clj) for running workers. An explicit [shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)) should have been called to stop this thread pool, but the thread pool implementation is not publicly visible.

What is a nice way to shut down core.async when undeploying an application?

Comment: The function shutdown-agents shuts down an other thread pool unrelated to core.async. I use that too but the core.async threads are still kept alive. They are in a different executor service.

Comment: How about [stopping the whole executor altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562079/how-to-stop-the-execution-of-executor-threadpool-in-java)?

Comment: this is exactly what i want to do. however, you see, i need a publicly accessible reference to the executor instance to call `.shutdown` which is not available.

Comment: Oh, I see now. `executor-svc` is closed as a local variable inside `thread-pool-executor`?

Comment: exactly! i wonder if there are any other ways in the jvm to shut down an executor service (and how to locate the one i need)

Comment: I think it is time for you to go to #core-async slack channel.